# How to send POST request to app.js after pressing submit button to show a view and render the values?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a number of value 0 on numberMath.ejs. My goal is to press a button. The button will display the view that shows the new value. The new value is calculated by a formula that I wrote in app.js.

Comment: Your example might be intentionally contrived, but is there a reason to do this server-side?

Comment: OK--no problem. Can you more clearly state the requirements, though, because it's a bit unusual. For one, why not use ajax instead of redirecting? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the old and the new number to appear you should send through the two as different values on `render()`

```
app.post("/numberMath",function(req,res){
  tempNum = num;
  num++;
  res.render("numberMath", {
    myNewNum: num,
    myOldNum: tempNum
  });
});
```

On the front end you can use javascript to popup the old and new numbers:

```
<script>
  alert("Old Num: " + <%= myOldNum %> + ", New Num: " + <%= myNewNum %>);
</script>
```

This will get the two calculated values to the front-end each time you push the `Formula` button.

Comment: 1. The script tags should work just inside the file. 2. You would need to add a parameter to the POST endpoint e.g. `app.post("/numberMath/:num")` look up express routing documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html  Routing Parameters.